# rundeckrun specify the host to run the a job

Tags: rundeck

I'm using [rundeckrun](https://github.com/marklap/rundeckrun) and been able to successfully execute jobs on Rundeck by running :

```
rd.run_job('b673461c5-f330-44a0-8323-a8f1d377b4b8', argString={'from':'RundeckRun'})
```

Unfortunately the above will execute the job on all nodes by default, I need to be able to run the job only to a specific host. According to the documentation http://rundeckrun.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide/jobs.html I think argString can do what I want but I'm not sure how the node name argument is specified as the bellow is not working :

`rd.run_job('b673461c5-f330-44a0-8323-a8f1d377b4b8', argString={'from':'RundeckRun','node':'server1.example.com'})`

Any help please ?

Thanks in advance,

N.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution from inspecing the source code :

https://github.com/marklap/rundeckrun/blob/master/rundeck/api.py#L316

The right argument to use is hostname :

```
rd.run_job('b673461c5-f330-44a0-8323-a8f1d377b4b8', hostname='server1.example.com')
```

Too bad this and the other arguments can't be found in the documentation.

Comment: _Technically_, it is in the documentation: [job_run](http://rundeck.org/docs/api/index.html#running-a-job). But not exactly easy to find I'll admit. If you were interested in looking deeper in the code, you'd see rundeckrun simply passes those params right through to Rundeck. And Rundeck uses them as such: [Running a Job](http://rundeck.org/docs/api/index.html#running-a-job) | [Node Filters](http://rundeck.org/docs/api/index.html#using-node-filters)